# how to get a distinct value and then group by it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to get distinct record through SSRS and not the query and then sum data based on distinct values. I am executing a stored proc inside SSRS dataset to get data. Below is the result of proc:

```
Company ProductID PayeeID PayeeName GroupID Profit
ABC     123       1       Brenda     1a      $30
ABC     123       1       Brenda     1a      $30
ABC     123       1       Brenda     1b      $30
ABC     456       2       Diana      2a      $45
ABC     456       2       Diana      2a      $45
ABC     789       3       Jonathan   3a      $23
ABC     789       3       Jonathan   3a      $23
ABC     789       3       Jonathan   3b      $23
ABC     789       3       Jonathan   3b      $23
```

What I need to do is group and sum profit for unique company, product, payee and NOT groupID. As you can see there's duplicate group IDs. I want distinct record of that. I have setup all the groupings in SSRS but don't know how to make it distinct for GroupID so my result is showing up as below in SSRS:

```
Company ProductID PayeeID PayeeName Profit
ABC     123       1       Brenda    $90     =(1a+1a+1b)
ABC     456       2       Diana     $90
ABC     789       3       Jonathan  $92
```

**should not SUM value of duplicate GroupID

What I want:

```
Company ProductID PayeeID PayeeName Profit
ABC     123       1       Brenda    $60     =(1a+1b)
ABC     456       2       Diana     $45
ABC     789       3       Jonathan  $46
```

**NOT summing duplicate values

Any idea on how to do this in SSRS and not on query level? Reason I don't want on query level is because I would have to create a table, execute proc and store its data in the table i created. In future if stored proc structure is modified then I would have to modify at both places for report to work. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following:

```
SELECT Company, ProductID, PayeeID, PayeeName, SUM(Profit) as Profit
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Table_1) as t
GROUP BY Company, ProductID, PayeeID, PayeeName;
```

Answer (score 0):

1) If it's acceptable, I would compute values of this new column within same stored procedure thus:

```
SELECT a.*, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN Profit END)
    OVER(PARTITION BY a.Company/*or CompanyID ?*/, ProductID, PayeeID) AS SumOfProfit
FROM (
    SELECT ..., -- Plus one more column
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.Company/*or CompanyID ?*/, ProductID, PayeeID, GroupID ORDER BY @@SPID) AS RowNum
    FROM ... final query from stored procedure ...
    ....
) a
```

Basically, this'll add a new column (`SumOfProfit`) to original dataset (!)

```
Company ProductID PayeeID PayeeName GroupID Profit SumOfProfit
ABC     123       1       Brenda     1a      $30   60
ABC     123       1       Brenda     1a      $30   60
ABC     123       1       Brenda     1b      $30   60
ABC     456       2       Diana      2a      $45   ...
ABC     456       2       Diana      2a      $45
ABC     789       3       Jonathan   3a      $23
ABC     789       3       Jonathan   3a      $23
ABC     789       3       Jonathan   3b      $23
ABC     789       3       Jonathan   3b      $23
```

2) The second solution is to transform (*when is possible*) stored procedure into user defined function

- Multi-step UDF function (if it has two or more lines) or
- Inline UDF function (if it has just one line; note: sometimes is possible to transform multi line stored procedure into a {inline|single line} function)

and the I would change the stored procedure thus:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE ...
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT f....
    FROM dbo.UserDefinedFunction(...) f
    -- ORDER BY ... ?
END
```

and for this report I would use (as datasource) following query / stored procedure:

```
SELECT s.Company, s.ProductID, s.PayeeID, SUM(Profit) AS SumOfProfit
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT f.Company, f.ProductID, f.PayeeID, f.GroupID, f.Profit
    FROM dbo.UserDefinedFunction(...) f
) s
GROUP BY s.Company, s.ProductID, s.PayeeID
```

3) Of course, if solution 1 and 2 are not applicable and [if initial stored procedure don't include insert into another table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117444/simply-inserting-to-temp-table-and-failing), for the second report we can reuse first stored procedure thus (I don't like this method):

```
CREATE TABLE #Results (
    Company ...,
    ProductID INT,
    PayeeID INT,
    ...
)
INSERT #Results (...)
EXEC dbo.FirstStoredProcedure (...)
-- and then 
SELECT s.Company, s.ProductID, s.PayeeID, SUM(Profit) AS SumOfProfit
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT f.Company, f.ProductID, f.PayeeID, f.GroupID, f.Profit
    FROM #Results f
) s
GROUP BY s.Company, s.ProductID, s.PayeeID
```

Comment: Note: I aware this isn't a SSRS only solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am here with a pure SSRS solution but it is very ugly and unnecessary complex. This solution was made for fun so I **don't** recommend use this approach against a large dataset and I would strongly recommend a T-SQL level solution.

Based on the dataset you posted I created the following tablix:

[image]

I've hidden the last column (details column) using Column Visibility window.

[image]

Using custom code you can extend the functionality of SSRS functions by using VB code. Go to `Report` menu / `Report properties...` switch to the `Code` tab then put the following code in the text area.

```
Public Function MySum(ByVal groups as Object(), ByVal values as Object()) As Integer
Dim found_groups As System.Collections.ArrayList=New System.Collections.ArrayList()
Dim n as Integer
Dim sum as Integer = 0
For n = 0 To groups.Length-1
    If not found_groups.Contains(groups(n)) Then
        found_groups.Add(groups(n))
        sum = sum + values(n)
    End If
Next
Return sum
End Function
```

In the selected cell (check the tablix screenshot) I've used this expression:

```
=Code.MySum(Lookupset(
Fields!ProductID.Value &"-"&
Fields!PayeeID.Value &"-",
Fields!ProductID.Value &"-"&
Fields!PayeeID.Value &"-",
CStr(Fields!GroupID.Value),
"DataSet1"
),
Lookupset(
Fields!ProductID.Value &"-"&
Fields!PayeeID.Value &"-",
Fields!ProductID.Value &"-"&
Fields!PayeeID.Value &"-",
CStr(Fields!Profit.Value),
"DataSet1"
))
```

Note the MySum() function take two arrays as arguments and return an integer, the sum of the `Profit` values in the given group.

It previews something like this:

[image]

> Caution: this solution was built based on the dataset provided in
>   your question, if the data structure changes it will not work.

Let me know if this helps.